# KeyPressEventHandler() создает исключение

Tags: c#, winforms

`System.ArgumentException: "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."`

```
namespace RFDW
{
    public partial class GameForm : Form
    {
        public GameForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Player player = (Player)Game.sbj[0, Game.player_id];
            label1.Location = new Point(1, 15);
            Map.Build();

            this.KeyPress += player.Move; // исключение System.ArgumentException: "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."

            label1.Text = Map.Render();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace RFDW
{
    class Player : Creature
    {
        //settings
        public new string name = "Player";
        public new string art = "☺";

        public int stamina = 10/10;
        public new int speed = 5;

        public void Move(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // Collision
            Collision(1);     

            // Movement
            if (e.KeyChar == 'd' && !right_col) ++x; // Right
            if (e.KeyChar == 'a' && !left_col) --x; // Left
            if (e.KeyChar == 's' && !down_col) ++y; // Down
            if (e.KeyChar == 'w' && !up_col) --y; //Up

            if (stamina < 1) stamina +=1 / 10;
            
        }
        public Player(int x, int y) : base(x, y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: `Object? sender` уберите `?`

Comment: Это не помогает

Comment: Тоже самое исключение

Comment: Нужно больше кода, где эта строчка кода расположена?

Comment: В классе формы.

Comment: Метод расположен в отдельном классе, но это наверное ничего не меняет

Comment: Покажите более подробный пример кода, метод и класс, где расположен проблемный код.

Comment: _Метод расположен в отдельном классе, но это наверное ничего не меняет_ - как раз наоборот, в этом и есть проблема, но как решить её - не известно, так как показанный код вырван из контекста и не позволяет сформулировать ответ.

Comment: Всё готово, я показал полный код

Comment: Вы уверены, что `player` не `null`?

Comment: Оказывается в этом и была проблема, спасибо большое!